# How to use YDLIDAR X4 in Nav2D

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

I'm back into ROS and Nav2d world :)
During my study I was using the robot from university where I implemented ROS and Nav2d into the robot.
I'm so glad to use Nav2d that now I want to build my own SLAM robot.

I have bought Lidar sensor YDLIDAR X4 which is support with ROS package.

[image: image description]

First of all I want to implement the Lidar by running Tutorial2.launch. How can I do that, if it is possible ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302047/how-to-use-ydlidar-x4-in-nav2d/) by [RosUser](https://answers.ros.org/users/25698/rosuser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2018-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use this the same way you would any other lidar. You just need to look at the specifications of what you need (a TF tree, laser scans coming through expected topics).

You can launch the laser node and see what the topics are, then see what Nav2D expects and reconfigure to use it. Assuming the rest of your robot has a description file to make the relevant transforms and its odometry updates TF, it should just work out of the box.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0